# Mapbox Android Sdk size

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

First I have forked mapbox android sdk and then uploaded mapbox gl native android sdk code to bintray and used it as a dependency in another project which increase my apk size with 25 mb .
On other side  in same project if a use mapbox dependency mention on official site of mapbox it increase the size of apk only 11 mb following is mapbox dependency :-
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'
.please help me in this case Mapbox and me are using same sdk for development why size differ so much

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you are loading libraries multiple times. You can check your dependencies in Android Studio under File>Project Structure>Dependencies>All Dependecies

Maybe you are loading the same dependencies from both the forked version of the SDK and the original source.

Comment: i have checked the code i am using only forked library dependency in project